# API key does not allow access from IP (Heroku)

Tags: heroku, ip

I'm currently trying to create a website that gets data from the Clash Royale game API (https://developer.clashroyale.com) but they ask my to give an IP address for my API authorization key.

The problem is that my website is hosted on Heroku, and Heroku has several (always changing and more than 10) IP's and I can only give 4 IP addresses on Clash Royale API.

When I give my person IP address and run my code the API is fetched without any problems, but when I push my code to Heroku and open my website, I get this error message:

**`Invalid authorization: API key does not allow access from IP xx.xxx.xxx.xxx`**

Is there any way to get a single IP address from Heroku so I can use always the same for my API authorization key?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer after hours of digging into the interweb :)

I simply used a thing called "Proximo" that apparently converges all of your websites possible IP's to one; see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/proximo